# Не могу составить http запрос на Си

Tags: linux, c, http, сокет

Вот мой код:

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = htons(80);
char* ip = "151.101.129.69"; //ru.stackoverflow.com
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(ip2int(ip));
int sockRequest = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM , 0);
if(sockRequest == -1)exit(2);
char* request = "GET  HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ru.stackoverflow.com\r\n\r\n";
printf("%s\r\n", request);
write(sockRequest, request, strlen(request));
char buff[1024];
int count = read(sockRequest, buff, 1024);
write(1, buff, count + 1);
write(1, "\r\n", 1);
close(sockRequest);
```

Postman с таким запросом

```
GET  HTTP/1.1  
Host: ru.stackoverflow.com
```

выдает `html` содержимое сайта, а моя программа выдает ошибку `400 "Bad request"`.
Что не так?

Comment: А путь кто писать будет? `GET / HTTP/1.1`.

Comment: Два пробела эквивалентно / в моем случае. Т.е. что так что так, результат один

Comment: Можно ли цитатку из RFC, из которой следует такая эквивалентность?

Comment: Попробуйте руками через telnet. У меня на `GET  HTTP/1.1` отвечает `Bad request`, а вот на `GET  / HTTP/1.1` -- `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` ... `Location: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/`, а в теле ответа -- `<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/">here</a>. </h2>`. Наверное Postman правильно обрабатывает переадресацию на https протокол.

Comment: а да, перепутал, нужно писать url. Но в этом случае выдает ошибку 301, как написал @avp. А в чем разница подключения по http и https протоколу(кроме указания сокету порт 443)? Или для этого вопроса лучше создать отдельный вопрос, а тут указать правильным ответ @avp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По [стандарту](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616), в запросе обязателен путь. Так что:

```c
char* request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ru.stackoverflow.com\r\n\r\n";
```

Comment: Ну вот даже не знаю, ставить вам правильный ответ или нет. Да, это решает ошибку 400, но ошибка 301 остается. Ведь вопрос был не в том, чтобы убрать ошибку 400, а в том, чтобы понять как составить запрос. В комментариях к вопросу господин @avp правильно написал про переадресацию на https протокол, но я не могу найти инфу в интернете.

Comment: @Belenot Если вы делаете это ради обучения, то рекомендую поискать в сети информацию о TLS/SSL-соединениях на си. Если вам нужно для практических целей, то лучше воспользуйтесь [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) вместо построения костылей.

Answer (score 0):

Забыли подключиться:

```
connect(sockRequest,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(addr));
```

Comment: Тогда бы он не получил ответ от сервера.